# Register mouse events in 2 divs at the same time?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, mouseevent

Is there any way to have a mouse event (click, hover, scroll, etc.) register on two different divs?

I'm currently playing around with an app that uses both a leaflet map (similar to Google maps for those of you that don't know it) with a canvas element (running Processing) layered above it. Right now I can either have events register in the canvas element by doing nothing, or I can have events register in the map by giving the canvas the CSS `pointer-events:none;`.

Is there any straightforward way to get a click into both of them?

An alternative would be to define areas where clicks make it to one or the other. Specifically, I'd like clicks on transparent canvas areas to go through, while opaque canvas areas register clicks on them within the canvas.

Comment: set a class, and call the .click() or whatever and then set your action to the class `$(".className").click(function(){  Your Action here });` and the action is whatever you want it to be, it can even effect both divs such as `$(".className").html('Affected DIVS!');`  Then just set your class name on both DIVS ... `<div class="className">`

Comment: in addition ...  you could `trigger()` a `.click()` for a DIV you can't reach ie: `$('.className').trigger('click');`

Comment: do positions automatically carry over? how do I deal with click-and-drags, scrolls, etc.?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you'll have to manually get and set functionality, such as get scroll Y get scroll X on DIV one and SET scroll Y and SET scroll X on DIV 2.  Same would go with hover position etc ..

Comment: so effectively if i set up enough of these things, i'll be able to cover the whole gamut of mouse operations? and it'll effectively be as if i clicked on each div simultaneously? i just want to make sure it'll 100% act that way before I go through the effort of writing all that code up.

Comment: @thisissami In theory, yes...

Comment: Yes, just use the trigger() event to call identical actions:  On click on div 1 trigger() click on div 2.  On hover on div 1, trigger() hover on div 2.  On scroll etc.. etc ..

Comment: I just converted my comments into an answer

Answer (score 0):

You could set a class, and call the `.click()` or whatever and then set your action to the class

```
$(".className").click(function(){ Your Action here });
```

and the action is whatever you want it to be, it can even effect both divs such as:

```
$(".className").html('Affected DIVS!');
```

Then just set your class name on both DIVS ...

`<div class="className">`

in addition ... you could `trigger()` a `.click()` for a DIV you can't reach ie:

```
$('.className').trigger('click');
```

In conclusion you could use the `trigger()` event to call identical actions: On `.click()` on div 1 `trigger()` `.click()` on div 2. On `.hover()` on div 1, `trigger()` `.hover()` on div 2. On scroll etc.. etc ..

Comment: and x/y values all carry through automatically? i'm digging the `trigger()` method that you outlined. If I wanted to be able to control a map like google maps/leaflet, AKA I needed to be able to click and drag to move it around, double click to zoom in, and scroll in and out to zoom, what events would i need to cover? `click(), hover(), scroll(), and release()` or something of that sort?